# what changes are necessary for ng test --config to work correctly

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have, as an example, these files:

```
***folder blog component***  
blog.component.ts  
blog.component.spec.ts  
blog.component.domSpec.ts  
blog.component.html  
blog.component.scss  
***folder xyz component***  
xyz.component.ts  
xyz.component.spec.ts  
xyz.component.domSpec.ts  
xyz.component.html  
xyz.component.scss
```

I want to be able to run tests like *.spec.ts and *.domSpec.ts tests using different commands.  I have been unable to get **ng test --config** to work.

**ng test**   which uses the standard karma.conf.js  works fine to run all tests that are like *.spec.ts

I have been trying to get this to work:
**ng test --config karma.conf.dom.js**  to run all tests like *.domSpec.ts

In the karma.conf.dom.js I have this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  let _cliAppProcessors ={};
  _cliAppProcessors[config.angularCli.app+'/test.dom.ts'] = ['@angular/cli'];
  config.set({
  files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.dom.ts', watched: false }
  ],
  preprocessors: _cliAppProcessors,
```

then in the test.dom.ts I have this:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.domSpec\.ts$/);
```

when I run **ng test --config karma.conf.dom.js**, all of the tests run, not just the tests named like *.domSpec.ts

Comment: And what have you tried, exactly? Have you looked at the existing config? The `tests.ts`?

Comment: How are you going to fit it all into a comment? **[Edit] the question.** Provide a [mcve], explain what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to run unit tests in one build step and tests that use TestBed.compileComponents() in another build step.   I ended up with two files:  test.ts and test.testbed.ts.

Here is the only difference in the files:

test.ts
`const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`

test.testbed.ts
`const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.testbed\.ts$/);`

I would run 'ng test' to run the unit tests,  then run 'copy test.testbed.ts test.ts' on the command line (Windows), and then I could run 'ng test' again to run the testbed tests.  Simple, I know.  I could never get 'ng test --config' to work.